# c# The value from textbox turns into default value when inserted into mySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datetime, monthcalendar

I'm making a windows forms application that allows the user to select values from `MonthCalendar` and then inserts them into the database.
I'm using following methods to display the dates in the textboxes.

```
     private void checkIn_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
     {
        var monthCalendar = sender as MonthCalendar;
        txtcheckIn.Text = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();
     }
```

The dates are properly displayed in the textboxes and I'm using however, when they are inserted into the database they are displayed as default values.
I'm using the following to insert values

```
    private void Insert()
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Reservation (NumAdults,NumChildren,RoomType,CheckIn,Checkout) " +
                    "VALUES (@numAdults,@numChildren,@roomType,@checkIn,@checkout)"))
        {
            try
            {    
                command.Connection = connection;
                connection.Close();

                // Enters Reservation fields into the parameters of the SQL Query
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numAdults", txtNumAdults.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numChildren", txtNumChild.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@roomType", roomTypeBox.GetItemText(roomTypeBox.SelectedItem));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkIn", txtcheckIn.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkout", txtcheckOut.Text);
                // Opens connection and checks if query affects Reservation table
                connection.Open();                    
                if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
                {
                    // If the query was successful, alert user and display updated Client Table
                    MessageBox.Show("Reservation Record Successfully Inserted.");                       
                    connection.Close();
                    displayReservations();
                    resetReservationFields();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Insertion failed, show user message
                    MessageBox.Show("Record Insertion Failed.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error Inserting: No fields entered. \n" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {                  
                    connection.Close();            
            }
```

The format for the dates in the database is 'datetime' and I don't understand what happens with the date from the textbox.

Comment: try converting your text to DateTime.

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkIn", Convert.ToDateTime( txtcheckIn.Text));

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer.I tried this and now it is 'String was not recognized as a valid datetime' error

Comment: What is the value in txtcheckIn.Text ?

Comment: txtcheckIn.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(); //I'm using this within a method to populate DataGridview

Comment: I want know value of txtcheckIn.Text = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();. What is displayed in DataGridView for this? Look, you need to provide proper information then someone can help you.

Comment: When I used Convert.ToDateTime it just started to throw an error and the cells stay empty.Without it, it just inserts '1900-01-01' in the cell.

Comment: use the "SelectionStart", this is a date and ok for sql. save this value to a variable you can use in your insert method (assumed you have an date or datetime column in your database table)

Comment: I'm using it like this  txtcheckIn.Text = monthCalendar.SelectionStart.ToShortDateString();

Comment: @KKKK , I think you are new. I want value of row.Cells[4].Value.ToString(); You can debug and get value of this expression. Hope you are getting what I am asking for.

Comment: Oh,sorry,I'm not very good at clarifying.I think I understand you now.Debugger shows the value is {Text = "1900-01-01 12:00:00 AM"} type string